# How can I delete part of data of one key in redis using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I have a zset key in redis. When I add some data to the key, I want to delete some data in the key due to keeping the data same length. And I want to delete part of data in the key using the score range. If the score in the range, I will delete it. How can I do it using python?

Comment: Solved it. I have find a redis method `zremrangebyscore`, you can send min and max score to it, and remove the content.